# R Session Aborted when attaching lldb debuger

Tags: r, rstudio, lldb

I try to use `lldb` to debug seg fault error in the R package I am developing. I've seen some other questions on SO which use `lldb` to debug R packages successfully. But I can't get it to work....

I first start a new `Rstudio` process and want to attach `lldb` to the `rsession` process by the following command:

```
(lldb) process attach -name rsession
```

And then `Rstudio` will say that "R Session Aborted" and I have the following message in `lldb`:

```
Process 20658 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fffb69b2bf2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait:
->  0x7fffb69b2bf2 <+10>: jae    0x7fffb69b2bfc            ; <+20>
    0x7fffb69b2bf4 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fffb69b2bf7 <+15>: jmp    0x7fffb69abcaf            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fffb69b2bfc <+20>: retq
```

And even I type the `c` command into `lldb`, `lldb` gives me message that the process is resuming, but `Rstudio` is still stucked with "R Session Aborted".

```
(lldb) c
Process 20658 resuming
(lldb)
```

If I click `Rstudio`'s start new session, I will have a new `rsession` process, which is not attached by `lldb`....

What should I do to debug `rsession` using `lldb`?

I'm currently using mac Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach worked for me

In first terminal window

```
> lldb /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio
(lldb) b fork
(lldb) run
# breakpoint hit - start second lldb
# after running second lldb
(lldb) cont                # first fork
(lldb) cont                # second call to fork
```

In second terminal window

```
lldb
(lldb) pro at -n rsession -w
Process 1428 stopped
....
Executable module set to "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rsession".
Architecture set to: x86_64-apple-macosx.
(lldb) cont
Process 1428 resuming
(lldb)
```

I am inside lldb and I don't get nasty message regarding failing session.

*Update:*

It was reported by @Consistency that using slightly different command in lldb might be required:

```
(lldb) pro at -n rsession
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Although it seems that I need to change `pro at -n rsession -w` to `pro at -n rsession`.

Comment: Great! I will update answer with your alternative settings.